# Need to transform output into a single vector in R

Tags: r, function, vector, while-loop, statistics

I'm trying to write a function that performs a given number (`n`) of t-tests on a random set of normal data of size `k`. The output should be a count of the total number of significant (<0.05) t-tests and a ratio of significant to overall t-tests. I wrote this function below:

```
StatPractice <- function(n, k) {
  i = 1
  length <- k
  size <- n
  while(i <= size){
      k1 <- rnorm(length)
      k2 <- rnorm(length)
      t <- t.test(k1, k2)
      p <- cbind(t$p.value)
      i <- i + 1;
      q <- c(p <= 0.05) 
      count <- length(q[q==TRUE])
      prop <- count/size
      print(q)
  } 
    cat("count of significant t-tests:", count, "\n", 
    "proportion of significant t-tests:", prop, "\n")
}
```

I've tooled with this in a number of ways, but essentially, the output is something like this:

```
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
count of significant t-tests: 0 
 proportion of significant t-tests: 0
```

Could someone help me figure out why the count is unable to recognize `q` as a single vector and thus unable to give correct output for number of `TRUE` values?

Answer (score 0):

You need a vector to store the p-values. Currently, the object `p` stores the last value only. You can create a vector before the loop starts (`p <- numeric(size)`). Within the loop, you assign the current p-value to the vector `p` at index `i` (`p <- numeric(size)`). The counting of significant p-values has to be done *after* the loop. Below is a modified version of your function.

```
StatPractice <- function(n, k) {
  i = 1
  length <- k
  size <- n
  p <- numeric(size)
  while(i <= size){
    k1 <- rnorm(length)
    k2 <- rnorm(length)
    t <- t.test(k1, k2)
    p[i] <- t$p.value
    i <- i + 1
  }  
  q <- p <= 0.05
  count <- sum(q)
  prop <- count/size
  print(q)
  cat("count of significant t-tests:", count, "\n", 
      "proportion of significant t-tests:", prop, "\n")
}
```

Note that `length(q[q==TRUE])` has been replaced with the simpler command `sum(q)`. Furthermore, the function does not print `q` but return `q`.